# Javascript: How to execute through entire code and loop again

Tags: javascript, loops

How do I make the code reprompt in a loop? I want to make the code prompt, and then with the prompted number, execute the following code. However, it continues to just keep prompting, even when I input a number.

In short, I want it to execute num1 prompt, then execute the for loop and display the content on the web browser as well as looping to reprompt for num1 at the same time.

```
var num = 10;
do {
  var num1 = prompt("Enter a number");
  for (num2 = 0; num2 < 11; num2++) {
  var sum = Number(num1) * Number(num2);
  document.write("<p>" + num1 + " X " + num2 + " = " + sum + "</p>");
  }
}
while (num == 10);
```

Comment: When do you want to have the loop exit?

Comment: Don't use `document.write` like this.

Comment: Your loop condition should be `while (num1 !== '10');`, referencing `num1` instead of `num` (which has no use at all), and looking for a difference instead of equality.

Comment: That is a typical behaviour in Chrome. In other browsers you do see the results in each iteration. I have posted an answer that solves this.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** If you are looking to add a delay between each iteration, here's how I would do that:

```js
(function display (p) {

  var num1 = +prompt("Enter a number")
  
  for (var num2 = 0; num2 < 11; num2++) {
    p.textContent = num1 + " X " + num2 + " = " + (num1 * num2)
    document.body.appendChild(p.cloneNode(true))
  }
  
  (num1 == 10) || setTimeout(display, 500, p)
  
})(document.createElement('p'))
```

---

Your problem is that `num` never changes. You should be checking whether `num1` matches a specific number (like `10`) in your `do`-`while` loop and then exit based on that condition:

```js
do {
  var num1 = prompt("Enter a number");
  for (num2 = 0; num2 < 11; num2++) {
  var sum = Number(num1) * Number(num2);
  document.write("<p>" + num1 + " X " + num2 + " = " + sum + "</p>");
  }
}
while (num1 != 10);
```

Comment: So at what point do you want the loop to stop? And the for loop *is* being executed after each `prompt` is completed; the problem is that the next prompt begins so quickly that you may not be able to see the updated DOM. Do you want to add a delay between each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your end condition is on a variable you don't use at all, and it should be in the opposite sense, since the condition determines when to continue the loop, not when to exit (hence, `while`).

Secondly, Chrome processes Javascript first before updating the browser page, and as `prompt` completely blocks Javascript, you don't see the page being updated with what just has been written with `document.write`. Only when the loop can exit will you see the actual change on the page. This is how it works in Chrome. Other browsers *do* display the results on the page in combination with `prompt` (e.g. Firefox).

Here is a work-around based on a timer:

```js
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    var num1 = prompt("Enter a number");
    for (num2 = 0; num2 < 11; num2++) {
        var sum = Number(num1) * Number(num2);
        // Add HTML. Don't use document.write as it will clear the page.
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',  
           "<p>" + num1 + " X " + num2 + " = " + sum + "</p>");
    }
    if (num1 == 10) clearInterval(timer); // stop repeating
}, 100); // Allow 100ms time for Chrome to update page
```

As your code now runs asynchronous, you should step away from using `document.write`, which would clear your page if run asynchronously. It is better to always avoid the use of `document.write` because of this.